# jQuery scrollTop event is not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need jQuery animate together with scrollTop to create a smooth scroll effect to my anchor links. In my current project this is not working. All the animate - scrollTop Events are doing nothing. I load jQuery 3.1.1 in the header. In my footer main.js i use the the following javascript:

```
$('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(event){    
    console.log("ScrollTop");
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 500 }, "slow");
    return false;
});
```

I can see the ScrollTop in my Console but there is no animation. I dont know what to do i tried a lot of things. I also tested it in all the different browsers its working nowthere.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your selector with `href` contains `#` gives a different meaning without the quotes. Once you put `#` in quotes, it works fine.

```
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(){  
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 500}, "slow");    
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/3vy7adh7/

Or

If you want to avoid the post on any valid `a` tag,

```
$('a').on('click', function(e)
{    
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr('href').indexOf('#') > -1)
      $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: 500},"slow");     
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/3vy7adh7/1/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 180
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;          
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thx for your help. It is scrolling but there is no offset and no animation. Do you know what the problem could be? There is no error in the console.

Comment: Set up a fiddle with your code and I will see what the issue is